# Insert a new record to many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a relation many-to-many between two models **Component** and **Page** and autogenerated table **ComponentPage**, I want to insert a new record to my Component model that has a value of page but I got this error: `InnerException = {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Components' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}`

This my code:

```
List<Page> pages = new List<Page> { SelectedPage };
Componentobj = new Component
{
    Pages = pages
};
Componentobj = await _httpClientComponent.CreateOneJsonAsync("/api/Component", Componentobj);
```

My Component model:

```
  public class Component : Entity<int>
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ResourceComponent))]
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ComponentsUserRoles> ComponentsUserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

CreateOneJsonAsync Method

```
public async ValueTask<T> GetOneJsonAsync(string url)
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        ValidateResponse(response);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
```

My add method:

```
public virtual async Task<T> Add(T obj, string createdBy= null)
{
    obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    obj.CreatedBy = createdBy;
    var result = await entities.AddAsync(obj);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result.Entity;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I believe you're trying to insert a value in the Id/primarykey column but the database is set to generating it.

Comment: I think @zAnthony is right about the error, but I want to point out, if you are using a version < 5.0 you may need to explicitly manage the bridge tables. [What's New EFCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew)

Comment: Thanks for comment, yes that is true becuase when I delete "Pages = pages" and just create Componentobj = new Component(), I didn't get an error but I need some way to do that, I mean creating a new record of Component and see also my record in the autogenerated table. I am using .net 5

Comment: Maybe you can do a for each loop on the pages list and then manually map each property?

Comment: Could you please explain more?, in create Pages are null!

Comment: Can you add the code for (1) `CreateOneJsonAsync()`,  (2) Your `ComponentObj` model, and (3) your  `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method (which should be in your dbContext)?

Comment: The database table `Components` has an identity column and EF doesn't know about it.

Comment: Hi @Stemado, this the rest of the code, I didn't add a code in  OnModelCreating !

Comment: And what is `Entity<int>`?

Comment: Guys, I have a solution but could you please review it for me? In add method: instead of 
`var result = await entities.AddAsync(obj);` I added `_context.Attach(obj).State = EntityState.Added;`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem but if you can please also review it and add explanation for that.

```
public virtual async Task<T> Add(T obj, string createdBy= null)
{
     obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
     obj.CreatedBy = createdBy;
     //Delete AddAsync(obj) and add the next line
    _context.Attach(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return obj;
}
```

This summary about Attach in microsoft:

- Attach will track all navigation properties by the context.
- For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Unchanged.
- If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Added.
- An entity is considered to have its primary key value set if the primary key property is set to anything other than the CLR default for the property type.
- For entity types without generated keys, the state set is always EntityState.Unchanged.

Comment: *If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Added* Maybe you should rather wonder why the key is set.